# Packaging a springboot application with a binary file which is inside tar after building

Tags: spring-boot, packaging

Hi Every one i'm new to the springboot and i'm making the application via this link

https://dzone.com/articles/packaging-springboot-application-with-external-dep

here i maked that application but packaging is not done in a correct way as you saw the link on this code you saw a start.sh file to start out application so, there we have to manually give the jars over there to run.

so, i want to make a binary file of my application should be create automatically with new jars

i have try many thing and taking my seniors help is also don't work for me...
i'm expecting some help from experienced people in springboot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article you linked to, and its sample project, date back from December 2016, using Spring Boot 1.

Spring Boot 1 [was deprecated 4 years ago](https://endoflife.date/spring-boot); since then Spring Boot 2 replaced it, and Spring Boot 3 was released 6 months ago.

I suggest you give modern and supported Spring Boot 3 a try, using https://start.spring.io/ and read the  documentation from [Spring official website](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/); even better, why not check out the the new https://spring.academy free courses website from the Spring Boot authors